# Hbase: Scanning with only one Filter vs scanning with filter and columns

Tags: hbase

When i do an hbase scan with a SingleColumnValueFilter, and no other parameters added it returns me 40000 rows.

> Example:
> table.scan(filter="SingleColumnValueFilter('info','collection',=,'substring:tweets_brazilFire')")
>
> Example:
> table.scan(filter="SingleColumnValueFilter('info','collection',=,'substring:tweets_brazilFire')",
> columns=['field:body_s'])

When i add the columns to the scan, it results 1967178 rows.

I am confused here. The column is present in other rows but it did not have the column value as i am specifying. Shouldnt the scan apply both conditions of returning columns and row only that pass the filter ?

I am using python happybase for this.

Please let me know your suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First from the API point of view, the Apache Thrift applies SingleColoumnValueFilter with another syntax

```
Syntax: SingleColumnValueFilter(<compare operator>, ‘<comparator>’, ‘<family>’, ‘<qualifier>’,<filterIfColumnMissing_boolean>, <latest_version_boolean>)

Syntax: SingleColumnValueFilter(<compare operator>, ‘<comparator>’, ‘<family>’, ‘<qualifier>)

Example: "SingleColumnValueFilter (<=, ‘abc’,‘FamilyA’, ‘Column1’, true, false)"

Example: "SingleColumnValueFilter (<=, ‘abc’,‘FamilyA’, ‘Column1’)"
```

The first syntax seems appropriate for you. `filterIfColumnMissing_boolean` as true, so that only those rows with such a coloumn exist will return. Versions is upto you. 
Hopes this helps.

thanks

Comment: http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/filter/SingleColumnValueFilter.html the new docs api shows i used it the right way

Comment: I am unable to get this syntax to work using happybase